# Use a string as parameter in R

Tags: r

I have the following string

```
wrows <- "c(1:2,4)"
```

(which is read from a database, therefore not just c(1:2,4)).
I want to use this in an expression in the function read.xslx (openxlsx) like this

```
       read.xlsx(inp_file,
                sheetn,
                rows = wrows,
                cols = c(1,2))
      )
```

How can I use `wrows` such that read.xlsx reads c(1:2,4) instead of "c(1:2,4)"?

Thanks

Renger

Comment: does `eval(parse(text = wrows))` satisfies your needs ?

Comment: Thanks,  that does the job!

Comment: This works here, but in case you have control over the format of the string in excel and are choosing it for this convenience ... **don't**. `eval(parse(text=.))` is going to do this, but it also opens up a lot of possible problems, including inadvertent code injection or, much more likely, errors that are not caught. If it is read from a database, use structured data such as `json`, as in `[1,2,4]`; or home-grown as in `1-2,4` with a simple parser that, when unexpected chars are encountered, it does something intentional (e.g., defaults to none or all or `1`). (Just my two cents, thx.)